# Iterating function arguments in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, functional-programming

I am having trouble iterating over the function arguments passed in to the following function.

```
(defn iterateDates
  [& dates]
  (let [ukFormatter (java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    (for [i [dates]]
      (java.time.LocalDate/parse i ukFormatter))))

(iterateDates "09-10-2019" "10-10-2019" "11-10-2019")
```

This however when called, returns the following error:

```
Error printing return value (ClassCastException) at clojure.core/getOldestDate$iter$fn$fn (core.clj:96).
clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

I am not sure on how to iterate over the arguments passed in and take each element as a separate value which can then be passed to another function.

My goal ultimately with the code will be to compare a list of dates and find the oldest date in there. This code just tries to parse each argument as a date.

Comment: This code won't run. You have a bracket mistatch at `(for [i [dates)]`. Please post the actual code. Also you have the body of the `for` wrapped in two pairs of parenthesis, which will cause the return of `parse` to be called as a function. Is that your intent? Also, please post the full stack trace. On first brush, that error doesn't seem to stem from this code.

Comment: I have been running this in REPL and that's where I got the error, running it as normal does not produce an error but neither an output.

Comment: I think you just mean `(for [i dates]`. I don't know how that would cause that error, but you're passing the entire `dates` sequence to `parse` at once with how you have it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```clj
(defn iterateDates
  [& dates]
  (let [ukFormatter (java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    (for [i dates]
      (java.time.LocalDate/parse i ukFormatter))))

(iterateDates "09-10-2019" "10-10-2019" "11-10-2019")
```

This version should work.

You wrote `(for [i [dates]]` in your original code, and it worked as you unintentionally specified:

1. It used a vector `[]` of `dates` for iteration, where `dates` is already a sequence.
2. The first element of this vector is the `dates`, which is an `AraySeq`.
3. `java.time.LocalDate/parse` tried to parse `ArraySeq` as a `CharSequence` and failed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the explanations. I realise now the issue and the code indeed worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd update the answers as I have found another way to achieve this without having to iterate the args:

```clj
(defn iterateDates
  [& dates]
  (let [ukFormatter (java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    (map #(java.time.LocalDate/parse % ukFormatter) dates)))
```

The map function will apply the date formatting to every element of dates and return it as a new list.